# Looking for a specific Java container

Tags: java, containers

I'm looking for a container in java, that will enable unordered insertion, and random extraction - something like a basket full of lottery tickets, out of which you need to randomly pick one. What is the best container to use for something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use an un-ordered container ? Your requirement will be fulfilled if you use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in Java to store values and then use [Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) and pick up its first element !

If you want to avoid duplicate elements in the Collection , then you can use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). To pick a random element from it , create an `ArrayList` from `Set` like , `new ArrayList<E>(set);` , shuffle it and pick the list's first element.

Comment: List is an interface so I can't instantiate it. Which List should I use? Wouldn't LinkedList be too much? After all, I don't need order..

Comment: You can use `ArrayList` . `Set` is unordered but it won;t allow duplicates.

Comment: This answer isn't entirely right. Only `List`s that extend `RandomAccess` fit the bill. Namely `ArrayList`. `Set` is a good choice if you don't need duplicates.

Comment: Whoa this sounds good - is there an array list that won't allow duplicates?